# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'user_agent'

Tags: python

I am trying to run this on my computer https://github.com/WuLC/GoogleImagesDownloader

But I keep getting an error of

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'user_agent'
```

even though I did

```
pip install -U user_agent
```

I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

from settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'user_agent',
]
```

delete

```
 'user_agent',
```

and Try

Answer (score -3):

I don't understand why you're trying to install/import `user-agent`, the module's name is `face_recognition`.

Try using `pip install -U face_recognition` then `import face_recognition`.

Comment: @YuheZhu It's fine, I wasn't trying to sound mad or anything. I apologize if I did.

Comment: This answer is more of a comment than a true answer. See [how to get initial reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139661/how-to-get-initial-reputation-on-stack-overflow-with-the-new-user-restrictions-i/139689) for some tips for getting enough reputation to comment.

Comment: @Zev I don't see how it isn't an answer, I gave a solution and it should fix their problem.

Comment: @Kaniel It was my impression that your answer corrected a mistake in the question Yuhe Zhu was asking rather than the issue itself (why after installing the module it still was showing as not found). Perhaps Yuhe Zhu can clarify.